# Why does Twitter have /1 their API URLs?

Tags: security, twitter

Can anyone explain why Twitter has a /1/ "root directory" in their API URLs?

E.g.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses
```

Comment: It denotes the version of the api...

Comment: @Chandu if you switch your answer from a comment to an actual answer, I'll close the question and give you the points.

Comment: Thx.Similar answers have been posted. pls go ahead and mark one as answer to close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fairly certain its the API version, to allow for multiple versions to run concurrently from the same endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

It's the version number. When they do a major overhaul they can simply put all in `/2/` without breaking compatibility.